# Keep question unanswered... even after bounty

Tags: feature-request, support, specific-question

My currently bountified question, [C#: transcribe WAV file to text (speech-to-text) with System.Speech namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768679/c-transcribe-wav-file-to-text-speech-to-text-with-system-speech-namespaces) is nearing its end of extra publicity and I don't think it will have a favourable answer any time soon.

By the looks of how the question went, the problem needs more research and related updates from time to time until I, or some other person, gets it right.

It will be better not marking any answer right now and making the question visible to others when updates happen.

Can anything be done about this by the moderators?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't check an answer, then no answer will be marked (no new answer get enough upvotes for the automated process yet). Only if a new answer get 2 or more upvotes, you are out of luck.

Every time you change something (editing), the answer will be pushed to the front page again. So don't bother.